# ¿Cómo almacenar una imagen en SQL Server usando ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, mvc

Tengo un proyecto de *asp.net mvc framework* y necesito almacenar una imagen junto con otros datos, pero al querer enviar los datos del formulario me aparece el siguiente error:

> La entrada no es una cadena Base 64 válida porque contiene un carácter que no es Base 64, más de dos caracteres de relleno o un carácter no válido entre los caracteres de relleno.

Encontré código en preguntas anteriores, pero los códigos están bien, el problema está en el formulario porque no me deja analizar las interrupciones en el código.

Dejo el código como guía:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AgregarInventario(Inventario inventario, HttpPostedFileBase foto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();
        try
        {
            if (foto != null && foto.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                byte[] bytes;
                using (var reader = new BinaryReader(foto.InputStream))
                {
                    bytes = reader.ReadBytes(foto.ContentLength);
                    inventario.Foto = bytes;
                }
            }
            using (var db = new SistemaInventarioEntities())
            {
                db.Inventario.Add(inventario);
                db.SaveChanges();
                TempData["success"] = "Equipo agregado: " + inventario.TipodeEquipo + " " + inventario.Marca + ".";
                return RedirectToAction("ListaInventario");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "¡¡¡Error!!! Revise los datos y vuela a intentarlo.");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Aquí muestro una parte de la vista:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AgregarInventario", "Inventario", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
    
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Inventario</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <label id="TipodeEquipo" name="TipodeEquipo" class="control-label col-md-2">Tipo de equipo</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TipodeEquipo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipodeEquipo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Marca" name="Marca" class="control-label col-md-2">Marca</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Marca, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Marca, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Precio" name="Precio" class="control-label col-md-2">Precio</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Precio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Precio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Estado" name="Estado" class="control-label col-md-2">Estado</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Estado, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Estado, "--Seleccione una opción--", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Observaciones" name="Observaciones" class="control-label col-md-2">Observaciones</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Observaciones, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Observaciones, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Foto" name="Foto" class="control-label col-md-2">Foto</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" id="Foto" name="Foto" class="form-control" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Foto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Espero haber sido lo suficientemente explicito. Saludos!

Comment: sé que no es lo que estás preguntando, pero no sería mejor guardar en servidor y después guardar el path donde lo guardaste? normalmente, cuando insertas imágenes pesadas o múltiples imágenes, tiende a volverse lento

Comment: Como menciona @L.Ronquillo Seria mejor que la guardes en el servidor...
Por aquí te dejo una respuesta de hace un par de meses.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/406663/subir-multiples-imagenes-asp-net-core-mvc-c/406892#406892

Comment: lo primero que debes sabes es que nunca se guarda una imagen en la base de datos Si preguntas PORQUE es por buenas practicas. 1-debes subir tu imagen al serviedor cuando tengas el codigo o lo desarrolles te daras cuentas que puedes capturar varias campos como la extencion de la imagen, solo el nombre de la imagen y el nombre de la imagen puede ser el que ya tiene o sustituilar por algun textbox, tambien puder capturar la direccion en donde se guarda ESO  es lo guardaras en la BD se te ara mas facil mandarlo a llamar, creo que con esos ten dara ideas de que hacer y buscar

Comment: primero que tipo de dato tienes en SQL para alamacenar la imagen?

Comment: Obviando el hecho que es mala idea guardar la imagen en la base de datos, por favor muestra la clase `Inventario`. La propiedad que contiene la imagen debería ser de tipo `byte[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error te dice claramente que en tu base de datos no puedes introducir un campo en base64 porque no lo traduces a base64, en tu código lo estás convirtiendo a un array de bytes, para que puedas insertarlo tienes que cambiar tu campo a **varbinary(max)**, entonces te dejaría guardar la imagen.

Tal vez te siga dando error al insertar y es porque al pasárselo a link tendrías que castearlo a [SqlBinary](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbinary?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Si quieres convertir una imagen a Base64 lo que tienes que hacer es:

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus comentarios y aclararme la duda, realmente tenia ideas erróneas respecto a eso, ya se solucionó el problema, efectivamente se tenia que convertir en base64 de todas formas.

Comment: Si la respuesta es correcta pulsando el tic puedes validarla para en caso de otros con el mismo problema encuentren la solución, si no ha sido esta respuesta te invito a escribir otra con tu solución