# guardar imagen en disco duro local desde un formulario de asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

hola buenas tengo una duda vieran que estoy haciendo una aplicación web con formularios y los objetos los almaceno en una lista, pero en mi proyecto me solicitan que para un formulario las imágenes las almacene en el disco duro local, entonces me preguntaba si me dan una mano ya que no entiendo del todo como hacerlo.

este es el Código de mi controllador que almacena el objeto en una lista

```
        public IActionResult Crear(Tours tours)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Almacenamiento.tours.Add(tours);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            return View(tours);
        }

Aqui esta mi vista 

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Crear">
            
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="nombre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="nombre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="nombre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Descripcion" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Descripcion" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Descripcion" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Imagen" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="file" name="files" id="imagenId" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Dia" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Dia" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Dia" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="return validarImagen()" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

pero al hacer un punto de interrupción mi vista no envía en la imagen ya que la manda null , entonces nose como es que se almacenan imágenes, aparte de no saber como la almaceno en el disco duro.

mi clase tours

```
public class Tours
{
    public string nombre { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public string? Imagen { get; set; }

    public string Dia { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que:

De la clase `Tours`, el nombre de la propiedad que recibe el archivo se llama `files`.

Prueba con esto:

Le agregué al formulario: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Crear" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="nombre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="nombre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="nombre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Descripcion" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Descripcion" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Descripcion" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Imagen" class="control-label"></label>
                <!-- <input type="file" name="files" id="imagenId" class="form-control" /> -->
                <input type="file" name="Imagen" id="Imagen" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Dia" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Dia" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Dia" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="return validarImagen()" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Saludos.

Comment: hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, vieras que probando aun no me funciona la imagen me la trae al controllador nul, te adjunte mi clase tours para que veas el nombre de mi atributo imagen, crees que ese es el problema

Comment: Obvio, como no hay match, siempre tira null. Acabo de actualizar la respuesta. Workshop recomendado: https://youtu.be/6LZG76aLykY te será de gran ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: match que es eso ?, bueno sigue sin funcionar, pero aun así gracias voy a mirar ese video

Comment: Match: palabra en inglés para describir la idea de "cotejo" en español, dicho de otro modo, tienes la propiedad A en un formulario y esperas la propiedad A en el servidor, "hay match", tienes la propiedad A1 en un formulario y esperas la propiedad A en el servidor, "no hay match". Lectura sugerida: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/406892/822 Saludos.

Comment: Dato importante, coloca un breakpoint y mira si estás recibiendo algo en la propiedad `Imagen` y por otro lado, ¿por qué un string?

Comment: no ni idea lo vi en un video asi jejej que se usaban un arreglo de bytes o un string entonces crei que el proceso de convertir y desconvertir con el arreglo seria mas tedioso y con el string no pero es solo una suposición

Comment: Dato importante, si esta respuesta **no** ha solucionado tu problema en sí, evita marcarla como aceptada. De este modo evitas que la gente que tenga tu mismo escenario intente algo que **no** le va a resultar.

Comment: ok perdón lo cambiare